# While adding a new component to a new page in experience editor not getting added in sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore, experience-editor

I am trying to add a new component with a new datasource creating through experience editor, but the component is notgetting added for the first time in Sitecore 9.3. Any suggestions what needs to be done?

Comment: What is the code of your component? does it ALWAYS renders at least empty div?

Comment: Our code just renders the content from one field in sitecore in a particular div structure and it is just a view rendering.

Answer (score 0):

When using experience editor, you are editing the final layout by default. You can switch to shared layout by clicking on the **Presentation** tab and then choose the **Shared Layout**. I would suggest you take a look, after saving your newly added rendering, that is is actually being added into the presentation details of the page you are editing.

Other than that, you should make sure that your view rendering (say : `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/YourRendering`) 's **Path** and **Model** field are filled with valid data. You would end up with logs if either is invalid, but I am unaware of if there are logs in your browser. (If you end up having relevant errors, please update your question accordingly)

If none of the above is helping, you should make that within your view.cshtml, you dont have any conditions that may affects the view to render properly. Try with some pure html and see if you can make it work.